# using bindAll in a constructor

Tags: underscore.js

i wanted to use _.bindAll(this) in a constructor.

unfortunately, i realized the prototype functions are not considered "own properties", so _.bindAll via _.functions won't find them.

is there another way to get at the prototype functions of "this" in a constructor functions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the dreaded for-in loop, since that iterates over prototype properties as well.

Comment: yeah, that seems ugly. might catch stuff i don't want.

Comment: I really don't see any alternative, though, short of traversing the prototype chain.